# Standard ml function in datatype problem

Tags: sml, ml

I have to create a function about peano numbers defined as the following datatype:

```
datatype 'a peano = P of ('a -> 'a) * 'a -> 'a
val zero = P(fn (f, x) => x)
```

The function that I have to implement finds the succesive peano number of the peano parameter `P(p)`. This is what I have written:

```
fun suc (P(p)) = case P(p) of P(fn(f,x)=>x) => P(fn(f,x)=>f(x));
```

The problem is that i get these errors:

```
stdIn:4.33-4.36 Error: syntax error: deleting FN LPAREN
stdIn:4.43 Error: syntax error found at RPAREN
```

I don't know what Im doing wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in this code.  The one the compiler is whining about is that you have a function definition

```
fn (f,x) => x
```

on the left-hand side of a `case` arm, where only *patterns* are permitted.

Some other problems:

1. Redundant parentheses make the code hard to read ([advice is available](http://tinyurl.com/yabryda) on removing them).
2. Your `case` expression is redundant; in the function definition

   ```
    fun suc (P p) = ...
   ```

   it should be possible just to compute with `p` without any more case analysis.
3. Since `P` carries a function, you will probably have an easier time if you write

   ```
    fun suc (P f) = ...
   ```

   and make sure that in the result, `f` is applied to a pair (as required by the datatype declarations).